# second highest salary in table in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

second highest salary in table in sql

```
select * from emp e where
 2 =(select count(distinct sal) from emp where e.sal<=sal)
```

I am unable to understand this query...can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze the inner query: you are selecting all the distinct salaries there are more or equal than a predefined salary, which is the salary of the outer query.

So, for EVERY row, you are searching and counting all the other rows with a salary greater or equal that one, and you finally select the one which have a value of 2, which is exactly the second highest salary (because the second highest salary has just 2 salary greater or equal itself: the greater salary at all, and itself).

Tremendous inefficent, because for every row you re-scan the entire table, but funny :)

Comment: +1 If salary is indexed you "only" end up scanning half the table on average though!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very inefficient way of doing it.

It uses a correlated sub query. Conceptually for each row in the outer query it does a self join back into the `emp` table and counts the number of distinct salary values less than or equal to the current salary. If this is 2 then this salary is the 2nd highest salary in the table.

This is known as a "triangular join" and as the number of rows increase the work required grows exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

We can get nth highest salary from table, see below sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary, name, id 
       FROM emp_salary 
       GROUP BY salary 
       ORDER BY salary DESC 
       LIMIT N-1,1;
```

For example : Find second highest salary

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary, name, id 
       FROM emp_salary 
       GROUP BY salary 
       ORDER BY salary DESC 
       LIMIT 1,1;
```

We can get nth lowest salary from table, see below sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary, name, id 
       FROM emp_salary 
       GROUP BY salary 
       ORDER BY salary ASC 
       LIMIT N-1,1;
```

For example : Find second lowest salary

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary, name, id 
       FROM emp_salary 
       GROUP BY salary 
       ORDER BY salary ASC 
       LIMIT 1,1;
```